# Melody for haiku poem?

Tags: melody

Are there any popular melody or tune to sing a [haiku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku) poem?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure whether this question fits this site.

Comment: I think it does.  I believe there are certain poetic forms which are mapped to music in a traditional way, so it's a fair quetsion.  Whether anyone is an expert in Traditional Japanese song forms on the site is a different matter!

Comment: Agreed; this applies to an entire class of musical text-setting, so I don't believe the "song identification" off-topic criteria applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No single melody can properly fit all English haiku, because each poem stresses different syllables.  This may also be true for 5-7-5 haiku in other Western languages.  Furthermore, some scholars argue that 5-7-5  poorly translates the Japanese concept, and that other syllable counts are justifiable.  In that case, even the *number* of syllables is not known.  The only possible melody would be something like a [Psalm tone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciting_tone#Regular_psalm_tones).

Similarly, in Japanese poems, the lengths of [mora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mora_%28linguistics%29) may differ.  The quality of word underlay in Japanese surely depends as much on mora lengths as it does in English on scansion.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps each haiku may need a slightly different melody. For a non-serious haiku, try a 12-bar blues. Or maybe a Folia (using the 9-bar version).

None of these short poetic forms seems too easy to set. Omar Khayyam's stuff isn't easy either.